# Paytm payment gateway showing error in php

Tags: php, payment-gateway, paytm

I am trying to integrate paytm(merchant/developer account) with Php.I created account in developer paytm and put keys api and secret keys in config file But i am getting error

"Something went wrong It may be due to any of these reasons:
    Session expired due to inactivity
    Our system encountered an obstacle".

And page redirect to following url

```
"https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/{url}"
```

Here is my TxnTest.php file

```
<?php
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

?>
    <form method="post" action="pgRedirect.php">
        <table border="1">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>S.No</th>
                    <th>Label</th>
                    <th>Value</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td><label>ORDER_ID::*</label></td>
                    <td><input id="ORDER_ID" tabindex="1" maxlength="20" size="20"
                        name="ORDER_ID" autocomplete="off"
                        value="<?php echo  "ORDS" . rand(10000,99999999)?>">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td><label>CUSTID ::*</label></td>
                    <td><input id="CUST_ID" tabindex="2" maxlength="12" size="12" name="CUST_ID" autocomplete="off" value="CUST001"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td><label>INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID ::*</label></td>
                    <td><input id="INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID" tabindex="4" maxlength="12" size="12" name="INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID" autocomplete="off" value="Retail"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td><label>Channel ::*</label></td>
                    <td><input id="CHANNEL_ID" tabindex="4" maxlength="12"
                        size="12" name="CHANNEL_ID" autocomplete="off" value="WEB">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td><label>txnAmount*</label></td>
                    <td><input title="TXN_AMOUNT" tabindex="10"
                        type="text" name="TXN_AMOUNT"
                        value="1">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input value="CheckOut" type="submit"   onclick=""></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        * - Mandatory Fields
    </form>
```

Here is my pgRedirect.php file code

```
<?php
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
// following files need to be included
require_once("./lib/config_paytm.php");
require_once("./lib/encdec_paytm.php");

$checkSum = "";
$paramList = array();

$ORDER_ID = $_POST["ORDER_ID"];
$CUST_ID = $_POST["CUST_ID"];
$INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID = $_POST["INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"];
$CHANNEL_ID = $_POST["CHANNEL_ID"];
$TXN_AMOUNT = $_POST["TXN_AMOUNT"];

// Create an array having all required parameters for creating checksum.
$paramList["MID"] = PAYTM_MERCHANT_MID;
$paramList["ORDER_ID"] = $ORDER_ID;
$paramList["CUST_ID"] = $CUST_ID;
$paramList["INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"] = $INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID;
$paramList["CHANNEL_ID"] = $CHANNEL_ID;
$paramList["TXN_AMOUNT"] = $TXN_AMOUNT;
$paramList["WEBSITE"] = PAYTM_MERCHANT_WEBSITE;

/*
$paramList["CALLBACK_URL"] = "http://localhost/PaytmKit/pgResponse.php";
$paramList["MSISDN"] = $MSISDN; //Mobile number of customer
$paramList["EMAIL"] = $EMAIL; //Email ID of customer
$paramList["VERIFIED_BY"] = "EMAIL"; //
$paramList["IS_USER_VERIFIED"] = "YES"; //

*/

//Here checksum string will return by getChecksumFromArray() function.
$checkSum = getChecksumFromArray($paramList,PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY);

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Merchant Check Out Page</title>
</head>
<?php echo PAYTM_TXN_URL; 

?>

<body>
    <center><h1>Please do not refresh this page...</h1></center>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo PAYTM_TXN_URL ?>" name="f1">
        <table border="1">
            <tbody>
            <?php
            foreach($paramList as $name => $value) {
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="' . $name .'" value="' . $value . '">';
            }
            ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="CHECKSUMHASH" value="<?php echo $checkSum ?>">
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.f1.submit();
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my config_paytm.php

```
<?php

define('PAYTM_ENVIRONMENT', 'TEST'); // PROD
define('PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'); //Change this constant's value with Merchant key received from Paytm.
define('PAYTM_MERCHANT_MID', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'); //Change this constant's value with MID (Merchant ID) received from Paytm.
define('PAYTM_MERCHANT_WEBSITE', 'http://myurl/testd/paytm/index.php'); //Change this constant's value with Website name received from Paytm.

$PAYTM_STATUS_QUERY_NEW_URL='https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/merchant-status/getTxnStatus';
$PAYTM_TXN_URL='https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/processTransaction';
if (PAYTM_ENVIRONMENT == 'PROD') {
    $PAYTM_STATUS_QUERY_NEW_URL='https://securegw.paytm.in/merchant-status/getTxnStatus';
    $PAYTM_TXN_URL='https://securegw.paytm.in/theia/processTransaction';
}

define('PAYTM_REFUND_URL', '');
define('PAYTM_STATUS_QUERY_URL', $PAYTM_STATUS_QUERY_NEW_URL);
define('PAYTM_STATUS_QUERY_NEW_URL', $PAYTM_STATUS_QUERY_NEW_URL);
define('PAYTM_TXN_URL', $PAYTM_TXN_URL);
?>
```

Comment: if the error message you're getting is payment gateway specific, it might be better to check out their documentation, it would help you more than pasting that big block of code you got there

Comment: check paytm docs about "Session expired due to inactivity Our system encountered an obstacle"